# Convertir consulta en procedimiento almacenado a JSON en POSTGRES

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Hola que tal estoy realizando un procedimiento almacenado en POSTGRES de tipo GET. Quiero consultar la información desde este pero me manda el siguiente error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION p.products(_p_id TEXT)
RETURNS TABLE (
_name TEXT
, _total MONEY
, _products SMALLINT) AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY SELECT row_to_json(t) FROM (SELECT id,
(
    SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(d)))
    FROM(
            SELECT name
            , total
            , products
        ) d
) as productss
FROM a.products
WHERE CAST(p_id as TEXT) like _p_id
)t;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

El error que me da es el siguiente:

> structure of query does not match function result type

Answer (score 2):

El error te está indicando el problema. Tu consulta devuelve registros con una columna de tipo `JSON`. Pero la claúsula `RETURNS` contradice esto al anunciar que lo que va a devolver la función es lo siguiente:

```
TABLE (
_name TEXT
, _total MONEY
, _products SMALLINT)
```

Obviamente, eso no cuadra. La función no devuelve registros con esas 3 columnas.

Para corregir el error, modifica la claúsula `RETURNS` para que anuncie correctamente el hecho de que la función va a devolver registros con una columna de tipo `JSON`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION p.products(_p_id TEXT)
RETURNS TABLE(_row JSON) AS $$
BEGIN
...
```

Comment: No entendí lo ultimo, me podrías explicar un poquito más por favor. Gracias. @sstan

Comment: Modifiqué un poco la parte final. ¿Está mas claro lo que debes cambiar?

Comment: lo entendi de dos maneras... La primera fue está:
RETURNS TABLE (
_name JSON
, _total JSON
, _products JSON) AS $$
BEGIN

La segunda fue poner únicamente _row JSON....

La primera me sigue arrojando el mismo error: structure of query does not match function result type

La segunda funciona, pero me manda null....

Comment: Si te manda null, quiere decir que eso es lo que la consulta te devuelve. No creo que sea el mismo problema.

Comment: Probablemente el null es porque en vez de `like _p_id` debiera ser `like '%_p_id%'`

Comment: El problema es que _p_id TEX viene vacío... Aun no logro resolverlo...

Comment: Eso ya es un problema completamente distinto y que envuelve al que llama tu función. Si necesitas ayuda con ese problema, te sugiero de formular una nueva pregunta con los detalles relevantes a ese nuevo problema que tienes.